# ListBoxItems not highlighting selected item when bound from ItemsSource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've been trying to nut this out for a while now and meanwhile I've searched the internet high and low I can't seem to find an answer that fits how my code is made. I've seen the results of pages like [>here<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287857/listbox-does-not-highlight-generated-itemsitemssource-works-fine-for-listboxit) and [>here<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696443/how-to-programatically-select-an-item-in-a-data-bound-listbox-control) and neither of those work.

My code is very similar to the example code for a databound application, as follows:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="MyListBox">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Except for one minor difference, and that's that I bind the ItemsSource at runtime as opposed to design time, ie:

```
MyListBox.ItemsSource = listCollection;
```

listCollection in this case is an ObservableCollection of an object which looks like:

```
public class MyObject()
{
    public string LineOne { get; set; }
    public string LineTwo { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason I just cannot get the list to highlight the selected item in the list. Changing  to  doesn't work as Visual Studio does not allow both ItemTemplate and Resources to be in use in my code apparently.

Any help at all?

Regards,
Jovin.

Comment: The sample code posted works just find in a bare bones wp7 app (aside from the class being declared incorrectly, i.e., `public class MyObject(){}` should be `public class MyObject{}`. When the page loads and the items are loaded in the templated ListBox, any item selected is highlighted.

Comment: From what I can see when running the bare bones app they don't highlight :\ Unless something is broken on my computer. I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: Are you wanting a specific item to be highlighted when loaded? Or are you saying that when you select an item, nothing is highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They app in question for some reason just did not want to work. I followed suit and created a new bare bones app and it's now just fine. (Answering old questions).